# Why does the robot framework add quotation marks to a command string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

Why does the robot framework add quotation marks `""` to a string when executing it as a command?

Example: I am trying to execute a command through `Run Process` keyword. Here is my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Library     Process

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    ${X}=      Run Process      rm -r     Desktop\\sample.txt
```

When I run the above step in the robot framework, I see that it sends a command as like below (checked in log file):

```
"rm -r"  /Desktop/Sample.txt
```

Here `rm -r` should not get quotation marks in the shell, but the robot framework is adding them between the start and end of any strings with single spaces, which causes the command to fail.

I encounter this issue whenever I want to pass a strings with spaces to the shell.

Comment: Why not use [Remove File keyword](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Remove%20File) for that purpose?

Comment: Laurent, yes we can use but i just said my scenario with this example. my actual scenario is in the same way to form ipmi commands with multiple hex values as arguments.

Comment: That was not mentioned in the question...

Answer (score 3):

Robot will not add quotes when running the command. You see quotes because the error adds them to make it easier to understand the error message.

The first argument must be the name of a command. `rm -r` is not a valid name of a command. The command should be `rm` because `-r` is an argument to the command which must be separated from the command with two or more spaces.

```
${X}=  Run Process  rm  -r  Desktop\\sample.txt
```

To illustrate that the quotes are only in the log and not in the actual command, create a python script that looks like this:

```
# example.py
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(f"arg: {arg}")
```

Next, create a robot script that looks like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Process

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${result}  Run Process    python  example.py  one  two  three and four
    log  ${result.stdout}
```

When you run the test and examine the log, the following screenshot is what you see in the log. Notice that quotes appear in the log message for `Run Process`, but the script that you run does not get arguments with any added quotes.

[image: screenshot of robot log]

Comment: Bryan, if that is the case, in my actual scenario, i want to pass command1 output as command2 input and before to that, i want to convert the command1 output to hex so am handling it with a python keyword. when i pass the input like this ex: 0x12  0x14  0x15, i still see that robot adds "" to this though it have two spaces in between them.

Comment: @Venkat: The quotes are only being added in the log, they are not being passed to the command. I've updated my answer to include an example that illustrates this fact. The quotes are added in the log so that you can see which group of characters belongs to a single argument.